# AD PrincipalSearcher: Search where property does not contain some value

Tags: c#, search, active-directory, principalsearcher

Principal Searcher seems to do a great job when building a filter to find an object with a particular value.  What about without?  For example How do I build a filter to exclude everyone with "Joe" in their name. The code below would not work.

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

         //this is the problem line.  How to format to exclude values with Joe?
         qbeUser.Name != "*Joe*"; 

        srch.QueryFilter = qbeUser;
        foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
         { do something to non Joe users... }
```

....

Answer (score 4):

Seems it's not possible with `PrincipalSearcher`.

Two possible workaround:

1. Use `PrincipalSearcher` to get all users and filter at client side

   ```
   PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   srch.QueryFilter = qbeUser;
   foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
   { //filter out users with "Joe" in its name }
   ```
2. Use DirectorySearcher

   ```
   DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com/dc=domain,dc=com", "user", "pwd");
   DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

   srch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(name=*Joe*)))";
   srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
   // add the attributes
   srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
   using (SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll())
   {
       foreach (SearchResult result in results)
       {
           string dn = result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0] as string;
           Console.WriteLine("- {0}", dn);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. yeah I eventually did something like option 1.  It feels really inefficient to run through the list twice.
I had been trying to get away from directory searcher with the assumption that MS was replacing it with this principle approach so -must me more efficient?  Perhaps not.